Trying to add record they are just not showing
i am making a school project on examination management so it a basically a program that manages csv file records and all but my code just isnt it working i just cannot understand why here is the code
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

FILE_PATH = "the path to the file/exam.csv"

def load_data():
    if os.path.exists(FILE_PATH):
        data = pd.read_csv(FILE_PATH)
        print("Data loaded successfully.")
        print(data.head())  
# Debug: print first few rows of the DataFrame
    else:
        print("File not found. Creating a new DataFrame.")
        columns = ["rollno", "name", "father_name", "adharrid", "age", "attempt", "lastattemptscore", "dateofbirth", "address", "phonenumber", "email"]
        data = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
    return data

def save_data(data):
    data.to_csv(FILE_PATH, index=False)
    print("Data saved successfully.")

def display_main_menu():
    print('*' * 80)
    print('                                  WELCOME TO EXAMINATION MANAGEMENT MENU    ')
    print('*' * 80)
    print('1. Show Examination Details\n')
    print('2. Show Data Columns \n')
    print('3. Display Top Records\n')
    print('4. Display Bottom Records\n')
    print('5. Display Specific Column\n')
    print('6. Add a New Record\n')
    print('7. Add a New Column\n')
    print('8. Delete a Column\n')
    print('9. Delete a Record\n')
    print('10. Update a Record\n')
    print('11. Move to Graph Menu\n')
    print('12. Exit\n')

def handle_main_choice(data, choice):
    if choice == 1:
        print(data)
    elif choice == 2:
        print(data.columns)
    elif choice == 3:
        n = int(input('Enter number of top records to display: '))
        print(data.head(n))
    elif choice == 4:
        n = int(input('Enter number of bottom records to display: '))
        print(data.tail(n))
    elif choice == 5:
        col_name = input('Enter column name to display: ')
        if col_name in data.columns:
            print(data[col_name])
        else:
            print(f'Column "{col_name}" does not exist.')
    elif choice == 6:
        new_record = {
            "rollno": input('Enter Roll Number: '),
            "name": input('Enter Name: '),
            "father_name": input('Enter Father Name: '),
            "adharrid": input('Enter Aadhar ID: '),
            "age": int(input('Enter Age: ')),
            "attempt": int(input('Enter Attempt Number: ')),
            "lastattemptscore": float(input('Enter Last Attempt Score: ')),
            "dateofbirth": input('Enter Date of Birth (YYYY-MM-DD): '),
            "address": input('Enter Address: '),
            "phonenumber": input('Enter Phone Number: '),
            "email": input('Enter Email: ')
        }
        new_df = pd.DataFrame([new_record])
        data = pd.concat([data, new_df], ignore_index=True)
        save_data(data)
        load_data()
    elif choice == 7:
        col_name = input('Enter new column name: ')
        default_value = input('Enter default value for the new column: ')
        if col_name not in data.columns:
            data[col_name] = default_value
            save_data(data)
        else:
            print(f'Column "{col_name}" already exists.')
    elif choice == 8:
        col_name = input('Enter column name to delete: ')
        if col_name in data.columns:
            data = data.drop(columns=[col_name])
            save_data(data)
        else:
            print(f'Column "{col_name}" does not exist.')
    elif choice == 9:
        index_no = int(input('Enter the index number of the record to delete: '))
        if index_no in data.index:
            data = data.drop(index_no)
            save_data(data)
        else:
            print(f'Index {index_no} does not exist.')
    elif choice == 10:
        index_no = int(input('Enter the index number of the record to update: '))
        if index_no in data.index:
            updated_record = {
                "rollno": input('Enter Roll Number: '),
                "name": input('Enter Name: '),
                "father_name": input('Enter Father Name: '),
                "adharrid": input('Enter Aadhar ID: '),
                "age": int(input('Enter Age: ')),
                "attempt": int(input('Enter Attempt Number: ')),
                "lastattemptscore": float(input('Enter Last Attempt Score: ')),
                "dateofbirth": input('Enter Date of Birth (YYYY-MM-DD): '),
                "address": input('Enter Address: '),
                "phonenumber": input('Enter Phone Number: '),
                "email": input('Enter Email: ')
            }
            data.loc[index_no] = updated_record
            save_data(data)
        else:
            print(f'Index {index_no} does not exist.')
    elif choice == 11:
        graph_menu(data)
    elif choice == 12:
        print("Exiting the system. Thank you!")
        return False
    return True

def display_graph_menu():
    print('*' * 80)
    print('                          GRAPH MENU                             ')
    print('*' * 80)
    print('1. Age Distribution Histogram\n')
    print('2. Attempt Distribution Bar Graph\n')
    print('3. Last Attempt Score Scatter Plot\n')
    print('4. Exit to Main Menu\n')

def handle_graph_choice(data, choice):
    if choice == 1:
        plt.hist(data['age'].dropna(), bins=10, edgecolor='black')
        plt.xlabel('Age')
        plt.ylabel('Frequency')
        plt.title('Age Distribution')
        plt.show()
    elif choice == 2:
        attempt_counts = data['attempt'].value_counts().sort_index()
        attempt_counts.plot(kind='bar')
        plt.xlabel('Attempt Number')
        plt.ylabel('Number of Records')
        plt.title('Attempt Distribution')
        plt.show()
    elif choice == 3:
        plt.scatter(data['attempt'], data['lastattemptscore'])
        plt.xlabel('Attempt Number')
        plt.ylabel('Last Attempt Score')
        plt.title('Last Attempt Score vs Attempt Number')
        plt.show()
    elif choice == 4:
        return False
    return True

def main():
    data = load_data()
    while True:
        display_main_menu()
        try:
            choice = int(input('Enter your choice: '))
            if not handle_main_choice(data, choice):
                break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a number.")
    
    while True:
        display_graph_menu()
        try:
            choice = int(input('Enter your choice: '))
            if not handle_graph_choice(data, choice):
                break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a number.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

so i tried adding records to the code and they were getting added to the csv but still the terminal when i run the code it was saying empty dataframe.
Edit:
More information

first when i run the program
with choice 6 Adding data

then it get added but when i try to see or edit the data in the program
there istrying to show data
and in the csv file it shows
inside csv

You need to provide a more detailed explanation of what is happening. What is the exact error message and where does it occur?

If the CSV file is being created with data then read_csv will give a DF which is not empty. Code works for me with a suitable filepath. You need to give a {MRE] which produces the error and remove all the superfluous detail which is not required to demonstrate the problem.

@OldBoy bro see the post edit for more detail

@user19077881 see the edit on the post its not really a error it just not working for me

You have posted three extracts of your application but without any clear sequence of operations, or details of what is happening. As far as I can tell you have started with no input file, added a single entry and written the data to the .csv file. So start with that file and show (in your question, not in images) the actual sequence of events when you start by reading that file.

Well I just tried your code, added a new record, exited, started it again, and it successfullt read the data frame. So, as I said above, you need to show us the exact sequence of events that you are following.

You are using choice 6 and then (without exiting and restarting) choice 1. But choice 6 uses the function call load_data() but does not accept or do anything with the return value. This is why a restart DOES load the DF. You need to use:
data = load_data()

so that the DF is actually read in without restarting.
